# How to login into an android application using web url?

Tags: android, json

Am doing a programme on JSON parsing. For this I have an web account that is having the some registered users, if the registered user login only the server will deliver an access token, for my app I created a login page and gave the url to verify the user weather he is registered or not. The application is well parsing the  json and retrieving the access token. when the unregistered user tries to login it has to show the error message, but the application is closing forcibly. and Am getting error when i enter the wrong password or username, when i check this using RestClient, the error message is in XML format where as am using JSON format for login. How can i set the condition for this?
I tried by using the below code.

```
valid = validateLogin();
if(valid)
  {     
     Intent in = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Welcome.class);
     in.putExtra("CLIENT_ID", client_id);
     startActivity(in);
    }
    else{
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "wrong id and Password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Here is code for Validating the login.

```
private boolean validateLogin() {
        JSONObject json = JsonActivity.getJSONFromUrl("http://example.com/"+id+"/"+password+"/1/higfg");
         token = null;
         try {
                 token = json.getString("UserToken");
                // System.out.println("UserToken:"+token);
                 if(token == null)
                 {
                     return false;
                 }

         } catch (JSONException e) {                
                 e.printStackTrace();
         }   

            return true;
          }
```

here is my logcat

```
03-01 16:52:55.463: E/AndroidRuntime(892): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-01 16:52:55.463: E/AndroidRuntime(892): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-01 16:52:55.463: E/AndroidRuntime(892):  at com.android.epay.Epay.validateLogin(Epay.java:66)
03-01 16:52:55.463: E/AndroidRuntime(892):  at com.android.epay.Epay.onClick(Epay.java:47)
03-01 16:52:55.463: E/AndroidRuntime(892):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
03-01 16:52:55.463: E/AndroidRuntime(892):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
03-01 16:52:55.463: E/AndroidRuntime(892):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
03-01 16:52:55.463: E/AndroidRuntime(892):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-01 16:52:55.463: E/AndroidRuntime(892):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-01 16:52:55.463: E/AndroidRuntime(892):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
03-01 16:52:55.463: E/AndroidRuntime(892):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-01 16:52:55.463: E/AndroidRuntime(892):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
03-01 16:52:55.463: E/AndroidRuntime(892):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
03-01 16:52:55.463: E/AndroidRuntime(892):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
03-01 16:52:55.463: E/AndroidRuntime(892):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Please help in doing this.

Comment: the application closes. There should be something in the logcat, most likely a stacktrace, most likely saying that you are doing network on the main thread, which is forbidden

Comment: please paste logcat where app is got crashed

Comment: it is showing the error at valid = validateLogin(); and                  token = json.getString("UserToken");

Answer (score 0):

The cause of the error is that the `json` variable is NULL, which means that JsonActivity.getJSONFromUrl returns NULL. I suppose there could be multiple reasons for that (e.g. no response from server, no network connection, non-json response from server...).

Comment: am getting the json values when i give the registered users name. the problem with this is only when i tried for unregistered users.

Comment: Could you please post server response for the request from an unregistered user?

Comment: E/JSON Parser(1074): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value ï»¿<?xml of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Comment: Well, then it seems to me that the error is on the server side.

Comment: Perhaps you could post your server side script?

Comment: and i have one more doubt, if we give wrong data in web services, will the application closes?